# acquire monitor physical dimension

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine the true pixel size of my Monitor in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422296/how-do-i-determine-the-true-pixel-size-of-my-monitor-in-net)

How to get the monitor size I mean its physical size how width and height and diagonal for example 17 inch or what

I don't need the resolution , I tried

```
using System.Management ; 

namespace testscreensize
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\root\\wmi", "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams");

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
            {
                double width = (byte)mo["MaxHorizontalImageSize"] / 2.54;
                double height = (byte)mo["MaxVerticalImageSize"] / 2.54;
                double diagonal = Math.Sqrt(width * width + height * height);
                Console.WriteLine("Width {0:F2}, Height {1:F2} and Diagonal {2:F2} inches", width, height, diagonal);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

it give error

The type or namespace name `'ManagementObjectSearcher'` could not be found

and it works for vista only , I need much wider solution

also I tried

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
```

but it return the resolution

Comment: GetDeviceCaps might help.  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: there's a totally difference between the pixel and the true dimension of the monitor ,

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`GetDeviceCaps()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877%28VS.85%29.aspx) WinAPI with `HORZSIZE` and `VERTSIZE` parameters.

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

private const int HORZSIZE = 4;
private const int VERTSIZE = 6;
private const double MM_TO_INCH_CONVERSION_FACTOR = 25.4;

void  Foo()
{
    var hDC = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle).GetHdc();
    int horizontalSizeInMilliMeters = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZSIZE);
    double horizontalSizeInInches = horizontalSizeInMilliMeters / MM_TO_INCH_CONVERSION_FACTOR;
    int vertivalSizeInMilliMeters = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTSIZE);
    double verticalSizeInInches = vertivalSizeInMilliMeters / MM_TO_INCH_CONVERSION_FACTOR;
}
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. It worked out perfect for me. I was even able to copy/paste. The only thing not explicitly stated here is that this requires the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the screen resolution of the current screen by using `SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width` and `SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height`. The number of pixels per inch you can get from a `Graphics` object: `Graphics.DpiX` and `Graphics.DpiY`. The rest is just a simple equation (Pythagoras). I hope that helps,
David.

Comment: double MonitorSize = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width / Graphics.DpiX) + Math.Pow(SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height / Graphics.DpiY))

Comment: I think that should work, although I haven't tested it yet

Comment: execuse me which Graphics do u mean by , forgive me but I am new to this

Comment: Im sorry, I didn't make that clear. A `Graphics` object is used to paint on, for example images or controls. It is contained in the `System.Drawing` namespace. You can also get a `Graphics` object from the desktop. This `Graphics` object should contain the DPI of the whole screen. You can get the `Graphics` object by using the following code: `DesktopGraphics = Graphics.FromHdc(GetDC(IntPtr.Zero));`. Then you can just calculate the monitor size (in inches) by using the code above (you need to use DesktopGraphics instead of Graphics, though). I hope this is the answer you were looking for.