# How can I determine the screen width?

Tags: c#, wpf, parallels

I'm using a Win 8.1 virtual machine inside Parallels Desktop on a MacBook Retina.

I use this code to determine the width of the actual screen

```
var primaryWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
```

Unfortunately it delivers a wrong value of 1536 than the expected 1920.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Looks like dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422296/how-do-i-determine-the-true-pixel-size-of-my-monitor-in-net; you may not be in luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant tell you if this solves the problem but you can try it.

If you are getting different resolution on .NET's

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
```

and

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
```

than your current resolution settings, you might wanna check out your viewing settings.

To do so, go to your desktop, right click, and select "Screen resolution".

Then, click on "Make text and other items larger or smaller"

After this, click on the Smaller - 100% radio button.

it solves the problem for me once but again , cant say if it will solves your problem. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Didn't thought this could be the problem.

Comment: either did i the first time i use this but it happens, and it can become a huge problem if you dont keep this in mind