# How do GUI developers deal with variable pixel densities?

Tags: user-interface, pixel, screen-resolution

Todays displays have a quite huge range in size and resolution. For example, my 34.5cm × 19.5cm display (resulting in a diagonal of 39.6cm or 15.6") has 1366 × 768 pixels, whereas the MacBook Pro (3rd generation) with a 15" diagonal has 2880×1800 pixels.

Multiple people complained that everything is too small with such high resolution displays (see [example](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2104309/small-1080p-resolution.html)). That is simple to explain when developers use pixels to define their GUI. For "traditional displays", this is not a big problem as the pixels might have about the same size on most monitors. But on the new monitors with much higher pixel density the pixels are simply smaller.

So how can / should user interface developers deal with that problem? Is it possible to get the physical size of the screen? Is it possible to set physical sizes instead of pixel-based ones? Is that still a problem (it's been a while since I last read about it) or was that fixed meanwhile?

(While [css seems to support cm](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), when I try [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_cm) it, it is not the set size).

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but I am a Linux-only user / developer.

Comment: Ah, which environment? Most of them seems kinda [messy](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI) today, and the DPI info may not even be [accurate](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75387/36973) in the first place. I kinda hesitate to add them to my answer since without correct DPI info in the first place, none of 'relying on toolkit', 'relying on OS', or 'handling the DPI on my own' could work.

Comment: @Martheen I'm using Linux Mint with the Mate desktop environment.

Answer (score 2):

> how can / should user interface developers deal with that problem?

Use a toolkit or framework that support [resolution independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_independence). [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt149842.aspx) is built from the ground up to be resolution-independent, but even old framework like [Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605(v=vs.110).aspx) can learn new tricks.  [OSX/iOS](https://developer.apple.com/high-resolution/) and [Windows](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/06/windows-8-1-and-high-ppi-displays-better-but-still-lacking/) (or [browser](http://www.tested.com/tech/pcs/460553-problem-high-ppi-windows-display-scaling/) if we're talking about web) itself may try to take care the problem by automatic scaling, but if there's bitmap graphic involved, developers might need to provide [different bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskProvideAltBmp) such in Android (which face most varying resolution and densities compared to other OS)

> Is it possible to get the physical size of the screen?

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/422557/529282), and developers shouldn't care about it. Developers should only care about the class of the device (say, different UI for tablet and smartphone), and perhaps the DPI to decide which bitmap resource to use. Vector resource and font should be scaled by the framework.

> Is that still a problem (it's been a while since I last read about it) or was that fixed meanwhile?

Depend on when you last read about it. Windows support is still spotty, even for the internal apps itself, and while anyone developing in WPF or [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) have it easy, don't expect major third party apps to join soon. [OSX](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/windows-and-os-x-boot-camp-running-redmond-at-retina-resolution/) display scaling seems to work a bit better, while modern mobile OS are either running on limited range of resolution (iOS and Windows Phone) or handle every resolution imaginable quite nicely ([Android](http://rustyshelf.org/2014/07/08/the-android-screen-fragmentation-myth/))

Comment: About the answer "No" - if the developer knows the dpi and the resolution, he actually knows the physical size of the device. At least the size the user prefer to give to the GUI, which is what the GUI developer should care.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to deal with different screen sizes, for example when I make mobile apps in java, I either use DIP(Density Independent Pixels; They stay at a fixed size) or make objects occupy a percentage of the screen with simple math. As for web development, you can use VW and VH (Viewport Width and Viewport Height), by adding these to the end of a value instead of px, the objects take up a percentage of the viewport. For example 100vh takes 100% of the viewport height. Then what I think is the best way to do it, but time consuming, is to use a library like Bootstrap that automatically resizes elements, even when the window is resized. W3Schools has a good tutorial on bootstrap and more detailed explainations on any of these options can be looked up with an easy google search.

Answer (score 0):

The design of the GUI in today display diversity era is real challenge. I would suggest several hints, mainly about the GUI applications design:

1. Never set or expect constant pixel size of the text - the user can change it from the system settings of the OS. Use some real-world measures for the text and check its pixel size when drawing. Provide some way to put the random size text in the boundaries of the window.
2. Never set or expect constant pixel size of the GUI widgets. Try to position them on the window in some adaptive way - according to the size of the window. Most GUI widget toolkits today have such instruments.
3. Never set or expect constant pixel size dialog windows. Let the OS to choose the size for you and then use what you get (X). Or, if you need to set some size and position (Windows), define it as a percent of the screen size.
4. If possible use scalable image formats for the icons. SVG is great for icons actually. Using sets of bitmap icons with different sizes is acceptable, but highly non-optimal as memory use and still will not provide perfect scaling in most cases.